# splitting merged words in python

Tags: python

I am working with a text where all "\n"s have been deleted (which merges two words into one, like "I like bananasAnd this is a new line.And another one.") What I would like to do now is tell Python to look for combinations of a small letter followed by capital letter/punctuation followed by capital letter and insert a whitespace.

I thought this would be easy with reg. expressions, but it is not - I couldnt find an "insert" function or anything, and the string commands seem not to be helpful either. How do I do this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am despairing over here...

Thanks, patrick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
re.sub(r"([a-z\.!?])([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", your_string)
```

For example:

```
import re
lines = "I like bananasAnd this is a new line.And another one."
print re.sub(r"([a-z\.!?])([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", lines)
# I like bananas And this is a new line. And another one.
```

If you want to insert a newline instead of a space, change the replacement to `r"\1\n\2"`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `re.sub` you should be able to make a pattern that grabs a lowercase and uppercase letter and substitutes them for the same two letters, but with a space in between:

```
import re
re.sub(r'([a-z][.?]?)([A-Z])', '\\1\n\\2', mystring)
```

Comment: This seems to generate the following: I like banana\1\n\2nd this is a new lin\1\n\2nd another one. To fix this change the replace part with \1\n\2

Comment: Tom, I think you might have accidentally put an `r` character in front of the second string constant in my example when you tried it out. The Python string `'\\1\n\\2'` is the series of characters `\1<NEWLINE>\2`.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `sub` function. See http://docs.python.org/library/re.html for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, interesting. You can use regular expressions to replace text with the [`sub()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
>>> import re
>>> string = 'fooBar'
>>> re.sub(r'([a-z][.!?]*)([A-Z])', r'\1 \2', string)
'foo Bar'
```

Comment: Dude. The dollar sign is not how you interpolate groups. :-)

Comment: @Brandon: Yep, just realized, thanks. Still thinking in Perl ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't have any caps except at the beginning of a sentence, it will probably be easiest to just loop through the string.

```
>>> import string
>>> s = "a word endsA new sentence"
>>> lastend = 0
>>> sentences = list()
>>> for i in range(0, len(s)):
...    if s[i] in string.uppercase:
...        sentences.append(s[lastend:i])
...        lastend = i
>>> sentences.append(s[lastend:])
>>> print sentences
['a word ends', 'A new sentence']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, which avoids regular expressions and does not use any imported libraries, just built-ins...

```
s = "I like bananasAnd this is a new line.And another one."
with_whitespace = ''
last_was_upper = True
for c in s:
    if c.isupper():
        if not last_was_upper:
            with_whitespace += ' '
        last_was_upper = True
    else:
        last_was_upper = False
    with_whitespace += c

print with_whitespace
```

Yields:

```
I like bananas And this is a new line. And another one.
```